# Discord.py | Unpin command

Tags: python, discord.py

Basically what I want to do Is make a command that goes a bit like this:

User: >unpin 10

Bot unpins said amount and returns: Unpinned amount in #channel

So far all I've done so far is:

```
@Bot.command()
async def unpin(ctx, amount = 0):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    channel = ctx.channel
    x = 0
    amount = int(amount)
    if amount == 0:
        await ctx.send("How many messages do you want to unpin, max is 50.")
    if amount > 50:
        await ctx.send("Maximum amount is 50")
    else:
        pins = await channel.pins()
        while x <= amount:
            for message in pins:
                await message.unpin()
            x+=1
        await ctx.send(f"Unpinned {x} messages from #{channel}")
```

The problem here is that the bot unpins every message instead of the given amount. How could I change this to make it unpin a given amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it more pythonic. Instead of using `while x <= amount: ... x += 1`, use a for loop. Also, don't double-loop. The second loop loops through all of the pins and un-pins all of them. An example of a better system might be as follows:

```
...
    else:
        for i in range(amount):
            pins = await channel.pins()
            await pins[-1].unpin()
        await ctx.send(f"Unpinned {x} messages from #{channel}")
```